# TestNG plugin is not present in Run configuration

Tags: testng-eclipse

I am going to use TestNG in my work but its not authorised to me to install testNG plugin from - http://beust.com/eclipse/
So I have download testNG jar and import in to eclipse however script is supporting all testng package and annotation but when I go to run the script then on run configuration TestNG plugin not found so I am not able to run script through TestNG.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete the testng that you've downloaded and use Eclipse marketplace to such download. You can find it here: `help->eclipse marketplace`
Then type `testng` into search and install `TestNG for Eclipse`.

After all you will need to create such file as testng.xml which should consist of:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
<parameter name="properties" value="Test.properties" />
<test name="Put your test name here">
    <classes>

        <class name="Put your class name here" />
        <methods></methods>
    </classes>

</test>
```

After all by right taping at testng.xml file you will be able to run your test as TestNG Suite.